# Why do I get "curl: not found" inside my node:alpine Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

My `api-server` `Dockerfile` is following

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /src
COPY . .

RUN rm -rf /src/node_modules
RUN rm -rf /src/package-lock.json

RUN yarn install

CMD yarn start:dev
```

After `docker-compose up -d`

I tried

```
$ docker exec -it api-server sh
/src # curl 'http://localhost:3000/'
sh: curl: not found
```

Why is the command `curl` not found?

My host is Mac OS X.

Comment: Generally, alpine images don't come with curl

Answer (score 65, accepted):

`node:alpine` image doesn't come with `curl`. You need to add the installation instruction to your Dockerfile.

```
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
```

Full example from your Dockerfile would be:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /src
COPY . .

RUN rm -rf /src/node_modules
RUN rm -rf /src/package-lock.json

RUN apk --no-cache add curl

RUN yarn install

CMD yarn start:dev
```